# how to add object tag to html5 video tag dynamically using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I would like to know how it is possible to add object tag to html5 video tag using using jquery or javascript

I tried by jquery but was unscuccessful (unable to view the video in IE8 and below browsers)

The below is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var configval= "config={'playlist':['http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg',{'url':'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}";

            var $source = $('<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="360">'+
                            '<param name="movie" value="http://api.html5media.info/1.1.5/flowplayer.swf" />'+
                            '<param name="flashVars" value="1" />'+
                            '</object>'+
                            '<p>need to install quick time player to play videos</p>');
            $source.find('param[name="flashVars"]').attr('value', configval);
            var $video = $('<video controls="controls" poster="http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg" width="640" height="360"></video>').append($source);

            $('body').append($video);
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've edited my answer for the sake of simplicity, based upon Katana314's comment. I think this is what you're looking for. You were missing the video src inside of the video tag (you could also define multiple source video encodings using the source tag nested inside of video tag).

The way you were attempting to append the object tag inside of the video tag wasn't quite right, so you just need to do that, otherwise you were on the right track.

I don't have IE8 to test at the moment, but this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var configval= "config={'playlist':['http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg',{'url':'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}";

        var $source = $('<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="360">'+
                        '<param name="movie" value="http://api.html5media.info/1.1.5/flowplayer.swf" />'+
                        '<param name="flashVars" value="1" />'+
                        '</object>'+
                        '<p>need to install quick time player to play videos</p>');
        $source.find('param[name="flashVars"]').attr('value', configval);

        //Added source of your video here
        var $video = $('<video src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" controls="controls" poster="http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg" width="640" height="360"></video>');

        $('body').append($video);

        //append source inside of the video tag
        $('video').append($source);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Doing feature-detection and splitting the code sounds like a valid option. Off the top of my head though, I can't think of a specific reason that user12345zomg's approach wouldn't work; normally, when the browser doesn't recognize an `<object>` or `<video>` tag, it just uses what's inside of it instead. What's with the explicit mention of QuickTime though?

Comment: Agreed. I just wanted to fix one problem at a time. In that case, once you embed a video in the video tag, you could do a $('video').append($source) instead. Not sure about the quicktime text... seems irrelevant.

Comment: I tried your changed version of code too. But the problem I am encountering is the object is adding to video but I am unable to play the video

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a similar solution as well, unfortunately, I have yet to find any example where `<object>` could be integrated directly with a `<video>`. There is an easy way to get an `<object>`, details below. I was thinking maybe a `canplaythrough` and on error a fallback to this QT plugin.

You can use the QT plugin from the [**`Safari Developer`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_HTML/QTScripting_HTML_Document/ScriptingHTML.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001525-2-SW1) site.

1. Get the [**`plugin`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/samplecode/HTML_video_example/Listings/ac_quicktime_js.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007723-ac_quicktime_js-DontLinkElementID_3)
2. Use as an external script: `<script src="ac_quicktime.js"></script>`
3. Place the following script block wherever you want to embed the video:

   ```
   <script>
   QT_WriteOBJECT('http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4', '640', '360', '');
   </script>
   ```

> Wherever you want QuickTime content to appear in your webpage, place a line of JavaScript that calls the function `QT_WriteOBJECT( )`, passing the URL of the QuickTime content, the width and height of the display area, the preferred ActiveX version (typically left blank) and any optional QuickTime attributes.

...

> At run time, this will generate the correct tags and insert them into your webpage. This example passes the URL http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4, the filename of a QuickTime movie in the same directory as the webpage. The allocated width is 640 pixels, and the allocated height is 360 pixels. The ActiveX version is left blank, so it defaults to the most recent version.